# Unexpected Output from an Out-of-Scope Poiner

Tags: c++, pointers, scope

I recently came across a bit of C++ code and I am trying to understand why the output isn't what I expect.  Here is the code in question:

```
char fun(char *p)
{
   char c = *p;
   (*p)++;
   return c;
}

int main()
{
    char arr[3]={'a', 'b', 'c'};
    fun(arr + 1);
    std::cout << fun(arr + 1);
    return 0;
}
```

Here is how my mind is parsing the code:

1. The first call to `fun()` passes the address to where 'b' is stored in `arr`
2. Inside `fun()`, `p` is derefernced and 'b' is assigned to `c`
3. `p` is again dereferenced and incremented to 'c'
4. The value 'b' is returned from `fun()`

Pretty straightforward to this point.

Now, the second call to `fun()` is where I run into trouble.  Since both `p` and `c` have gone out of scope at this point, I assume the second call to `fun()` will produce the exact same result--with the obvious difference that the return value will be printed to the screen rather than discarded.  However, instead of 'b', the result is 'c'--and in fact, additional calls to `fun(arr + 1)` further increment the return values to d, e, f, g, h, etc. with each subsequent call.

I understand that the value is stored in the stack even after the pointer goes out of scope, but what I can't figure out is how the value is still seemingly being referenced even after the pointer is destroyed.

Comment: You're passing the same address to `fun` each time, and so each time, the value at that address is incremented, and the previous value is returned.

Comment: All your questions are moot. The shown code is undefined behavior, and the `<<` operator may result in a random crash, due to an attempt to print the contents of a non-null terminated string.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik mind pointing out which part (or line) is the UB?

Comment: The one with the `<<` operator.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Because of how `fun`'s return might be interpreted, right?

Comment: No, because of how `<<` operator interprets its argument. The fact that its argument comes from the return value from `fun()` is immaterial. If the same parameter was passed to the `<<` operator directly, the result is still undefined behavior.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik that's exactly what I meant. I see I was not precise enough. Thank you.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik There is no attempt to print any kind of string. fun returns a single char, not a char * as you misread it, so this should be well defined, though it doesn't do what the OP imagines it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> (*p)++;

p references arr [1].

Each time you execute this, you are incrementing the value in arr [1]. That is 'b' the first time, 'c' the second, and so on.

Comment: Thank you!  Prior to posting this question I had already tried adding a `cout << &p` inside `fun()` and had already noticed that the same address was being passed each time.  I had basically forgotten one of the basics tenets of the increment operator in that it is actually assigning the incremented value to the incremented variable and not merely incrementing the value.  By altering this line to `*p = *p + 1;`, I was able to readily see what was going on.